# Linear recurrence period of GF(p) for prime P

Tags: recurrences

Could you please help with the next questions?

Let's we have finite field $GF(P)$

And linear recurrence of the next type:

$a_{n+2} = s*a_{n+1} + t*a_{n}$

The question is: what are necessary and sufficient conditions for the coefficients s,t for the existence of the period for this sequence.

What will be a formula for the $n-$'th element of the sequence?

POST EDIT:

Let's p=$2^k-1$
Is it possible to find all $s,t$ such that period will be equal to 6 ?

Comment: If $s,t$ aren't both zero, then the sequence is always periodic. If you exclude the first term, you don't even need this condition on $s,t$.

Comment: By the pigeonhole principle the period cannot exceed $p^2$. The formula for the $n$th element of the sequence will in general involve values from the splitting field of $x^2 - sx - t$ over $GF(p)$.

Comment: Is it possible to find formula for the period of the sequence ?

Answer (score 1):

Expressing the linear recurrence in matrix form as $$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+k+1} & a_{n+k} \\ a_{n+k} & a_{n+k-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} s & t \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^k \begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} & a_n \\ a_n & a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$$ we see that in general the period in a given ring is a factor of $k$ when $$\begin{bmatrix} s & t \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^k \equiv \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ in that ring. (Note that by considering determinants we see that this implies $(-t)^k \equiv 1$).

With [a bit of help from a CAS](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNkDlrAzEQhXv9imErCZTFTiBFSNK7MD7aRVkUSw4DOoIkcvz7zGgh6ynf995c5_G56vYKL3DM4TfliDacMX3I00kJsSc92lbwR05T1dCMhmmrYWOMErtb2EWCGw1bhqJ6n8hQfZNKXHOBXBxg6vF7DQ8aHs2TAKrPgqnJ4VCcL4Nmn-o6h4hFzzF03gY5XXwIHZT8zbLcv3HfO9ipLndOOmGjxogJow2zrTVf0Dbv5t6wSrWM5sIrpNyWSSPWmQ76oidIBTa5FXFXvmkNrrsv2Xdbsap_zObROrdQ-sjNrYP6A8y7b7s=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) we get the following solutions for order 6:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
t - 1 &=& s^2 + 3 &=& 0 \\
t + 1 &=& s - 1 &=& 0 \\
t^2 + t + 1 &=& s &=& 0 \\
t^2 + t + 1 &=& s \pm (t - 1) &=& 0 \\
t^2 - t + 1 &=& s - t + 1 &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The validity of these solutions in a given ring depends on which sixth roots of unity exist and whether there's a square root of $-3$.